# How to make ggplot2 stacked barplot not re-arrange x-axis and follow order of original data table

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis

I am trying to keep geombar from rearranging the x-axis on my stacked barplot.

Data frame looks like this:

[image]

I want to follow that same order for the group column (Female: HIV negative, Male: HIV negative, Female: HIV untreated, Male: HIV untreated, Female: HIV on ART, Male: HIV on ART)

This is my rscript to generate the stacked barplot:

> data_long<- gather(data_wide, Genus , abundance, Sextaecvirus:Phi29virus, factor_key = TRUE )

> ggplot(data_long, aes(x= Group, y= abundance, fill= Genus)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_col(position = "fill")+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent).

Here is an example of how the stacked barplot x-axis looks like following my code:
[image]

Comment: Try with `forcats::fct_inorder(Group)` which makes Group a factor with the levels in the order as in your data.

Comment: @stefan Thank you! That worked!  Used the code  > data_long$Group<- forcats::fct_inorder(data_long$Group).   followed by my ggplot code and it worked.